# React ref.current.scrollTop is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got div what is scroll-y scroll. I need to do some manipulation on the scroll event, for the website I am using Semantic UI. My problem is that scrollTop is undefined for some reason but the onScroll is triggered.

```
import React, { Component, ScrollView } from 'react';
import './ChatRoom.css';
import { Container, Grid, Item, Image, Header, List, Message, Icon, Form, TextArea, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import _ from 'lodash';


    class ChatRoom extends Component {
        
        listRef = React.createRef();
        
        handleScroll = (event) => {
            console.log(this.listRef.current.scrollTop) <- is undefined
        }
    
        render() 
        
        {
            return (
             
                                <List  onScroll = {this.handleScroll} ref ={this.listRef} className="ChatFrame" verticalAlign='middle' >
         
                                    {
                                        _.times(5, (index) => {
                                            
                                            return (
                                                <List.Item key={index}>
                                                    <Message className='ChatMessage' >
                                                        <Image onClick={handleClick} avatar  />
                                                        <Message.Content>
                                                            <Message.Header>Roman</Message.Header>
                                                  Hello how are you ?
                                            </Message.Content>
                                                    </Message>
                                                </List.Item>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </List>
    
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default ChatRoom;
```

Comment: why dont you give a sandbox or something like that ?? its easier to find the problem in a runnning example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistake here,

```
handleScroll = (event) => {
  console.log(this.listRef.current.scrollTop) <- is undefined
```

You cant read `scrollTop` out of an element, You prossibily wanted to read it from event, something like this,

```
handleScroll = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.scrollTop) <- is undefined
```

Comment: I just had event defined, but I tried and it did not work tho(

Comment: @RomanHrybinchuk can you give any sandbox link, I cant see what `List` is

Comment: It does not work like that but works with event.target.scrollTop, change it I will mark it as correct  =)

Comment: But still, I can get the scrollTop but I am not able to set it because the ref does not work Hm

Comment: @RomanHrybinchuk set what ?? no code of there above ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217458/discussion-between-roman-hrybinchuk-and-axuser264).

Comment: did it. where are you??